# Quotation Mark in URL Problem - ASP Classic

Tags: html, asp-classic

On one of the websites I'm working on, I have a link on each item page that looks like this (actual HTML taken from rendering of page):

```
<a href="contact-us.asp?subject=Question+About+12%22+Knife">
  Ask a Question About This Item
</a>
```

The actual code I'm using to generate this link looks like this:

```
<a href="contact-us.asp?subject=Question+About+<%=Server.UrlEncode(sTitle)%>">
  Ask a Question About This Item
</a>
```

When you click on the link you will see this in your address bar as expected:

```
http://www.somedomainname.com/contact-us.asp?subject=Question+About+12%22+Knife
```

So here's the problem. I retrieve the value on the contact-us page like this:

```
Dim s
s = Request.QueryString("subject")
```

**Edited:**
Then I put it in a form as the input field's value. It shows in the form field like this: ***Question About 12***

This only happens when a quotation mark occurs in the string. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce this behavior here (IIS 7/Win7,64bit). What's your platform?

Comment: I edited the description of the problem. I was wrong about not retrieving the entire value.

Comment: Why are you using the QueryString for a form post?, You should be using an HTML POST and Request.Form

Comment: @HKL1 Then I think gilly3's answer is the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have in your resulting html:

```
<input value="Question About 12" Knife" />
```

You need to escape the `"` as `&quot;` with `s = Server.HTMLEncode(s)`.

Comment: Always Server.HTMLEncode output from Request.QueryString and Request.Form, not doing so, subjects your website to Cross Site Scripting attacks.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess off the top of my head is that you need to replace the special characters after fetching the string, rather then using it as it is. Maybe Server.UrlEncode helps in your case.